# Fetch all rows of a ORACLE SQL query using PERL Script

Tags: oracle, perl

I need to fetch all rows from an oracle sql query and then loop through each rows using PERL.

Below is some sample data and table

```
create table t1 (col1 varchar2(30));

insert into t1 values ('row1');
insert into t1 values ('row2');
insert into t1 values ('row3');
insert into t1 values ('row4');
insert into t1 values ('row5');

commit;
```

i have written PERL script like below to fetch above table --

```
# connexion a la base
my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Oracle:'.$dbname,
    $dbusername,
    $pass,
    {   PrintError => 0,
        RaiseError => 1
    }   
) || die "Erreur lors de la connexion: $DBI::errstr";

print ("Connexion à la base de données $dbname avec $dbusername OK \n");

$requete = "select col1 from t1";

$sth_sql = $dbh->prepare($requete);
$sth_sql->execute(@row);
@row=$sth_sql->fetchrow_array;

my $size = @row;

print $size;

#$first=@row[0];
#$sec=@row[1];

print $sec;

print $first;

foreach $script_name (@row) {
  print "$script_name\n";
}
```

the above code is returning only one row and size of the array is showing only 1 element in it.

I need to fetch all fives rows and then loop through them one by one.

please suggest what i am missing here !!

I am using oracle database.

Thanks

EDIT :

I have made some changes and it is working fine now

```
$requete = "select col1 from t1";

$sth_sql = $dbh->prepare($requete);
$sth_sql->execute();
#@row=$sth_sql->fetchrow_array;
$sth_sql->bind_columns(undef, \$script_name);


print $sec;

print $first;

while ($sth_sql->fetch()) {
  $script_sql=$script_name.".sql";
  print "$script_sql\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `->fetchrow_array` function is documented in [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI). There you'll see documented that you can either use it within a loop:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT foo, bar FROM table WHERE baz=?");

$sth->execute( $baz );

while ( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
  print "@row\n";
}
```

to retrieve all rows sequentially, or that you can use the `->fetchall_arrayref` method to retrieve the complete resultset in one go:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT foo, bar FROM table WHERE baz=?");

$sth->execute( $baz );

my $rows = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;

for my $row (@$rows) {
  print "@row\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Corion. I have made some other changes after going through lots of documentations.
Posted in Question EDIT section.